# How to put a fixed sized frame around traditional form expression

Tags: output-formatting

The height of a 2D form of a polynomial changes depending on the existence of exponents, fractional coefficients, etc.  For use inside a `Manipulate`, I would like to put a frame around such an expression, but fix the frame size with the content centered in it. I was unable to find any `Frame` options to do this.  Is there a simple solution?  I tried.

```
PlotLabel -> Framed[Style[TraditionalForm[a x^2+b x+c], 16]], ImageMargins -> 5]
```

Comment: `ImageSize`+`Alignment`?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you were to edit your post to include code that could serve as a minimal *working* example of your problem. As it is currently posted you have not given sufficient context for me (and many others who might want to help you) to work on your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, what you probably need is first [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) (with its `ImageSize` option) then `Framed`.

What about this :

```
expr1 = a x^2 + b x + c;
expr2 = expr1/d;

fixedframe[expr_]:=Framed@Pane[Style[TraditionalForm[expr1], 16], 
    ImageSize -> {200, 50}, Alignment -> Center]
```

then

```
fixedframe[expr1]
```

[image]

```
fixedframe[expr2]
```

[image]

The size of the frame did not change.

Have a look also at the `Pane` option **`ImageSizeAction`** which tells what to do with the content (clip, shrink or enable scrolling inside the pane) if it's too big for the given `ImageSize`.

Comment: You can use these options in `Framed` directly without `Pane`. +1 nevertheless

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `ImageSize` is not in the official docs of `Framed` ... and `ImageSizeAction` (which can be useful for the OP here) is not supported by it, so I think it is better to keep `Pane`.

Comment: `ImageSize` does appear in the `Options` list for `Framed` so it's not exactly buried, but I concede the point.

Comment: This is perfect for my needs.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMcGee  *Please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!*